# Slow Connections to AWS / RDS / MySQL from External Hosts (Rackspace, Digital Ocean, Etc)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are in the process of moving our platform into AWS. So far, we have moved our database into RDS. I knew moving our database before our applications would slow down our applications, but I didn't expect them to slow down this much.

~1 second for initial connection and query
*Query selects 1 row of data from a small database (500K records). Query takes .08 seconds directly on the server)*
`select * from users WHERE id = 1`

~.1 seconds for subsequent queries
`select`name`from`groups`where`group_user`.`user_id`= '1'`

I'm afraid we are stuck with this until our migration is complete. Our application still works, but it's sluggish for our end users.

Have you done a similar migration? Were you able to improve response time of RDS from external servers successfully? How?